# Is this permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, authenticity, islamic-basis

I wanted to ask about the ruling on reading the question and answers on this or any Islamic qa website is it permissible or is it spying?. Thank you

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think it won't be permissible?

Comment: Could it be spying ? It may contain specific Persona stuff.

Comment: If someone has posted a content online in a  publicly accessible website then how is it spying to view ?

Answer (score 0):

1. There are no restrictions to reading about religion, only to what is acceptable.
2. This site and all that is published on any public website is published. It is not espionage.